# 2 pagination for 2 tabs on a page

Tags: wordpress, loops, pagination, tabs

From HTML to Wordpress, I made a page with 2 tab as below.
[NEWS and EVENT tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJiEW.png)

Each NEWS and EVENT will show the posts for its own category, then I inserted pagination.
I click on "Page 2" on NEWS tab, then click EVENT tab, it also takes EVENT to Page 2 (EVENT should be Page 1 by default)...I Hope each one has its own pagination.
I searched for Multiple Custom Loop in One Page with Pagination in many places but the advices quite different to my case.

Is there any way to fix it? Thank all in advanced!

page-news.php

```
<section id="news"\>
<div class="container"\>
<div class="warpper"\>
<input class="radio" id="one" name="group" type="radio" checked\>
<input class="radio" id="two" name="group" type="radio"\>

      <div class="tabs">
        <label class="tab" id="one-tab" for="one">NEWS</label>
        <label class="tab" id="two-tab" for="two">EVENT</label>
      </div>
    
      <div class="panels">
    
        <!-- NEWS -->
        <div class="panel" id="one-panel">
          <?php
          $my_query1 = new WP_Query(

            array(
              'post_type' => 'post',
              'paged' => $paged,
              'posts_per_page' => 3,
              'category_name' => 'news',
            )
          );
    
          if ($my_query1->have_posts()):
            echo '<ul>';
            while ($my_query1->have_posts()):
              $my_query1->the_post();
          ?>
          <li>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
              <?php the_title(); ?><br>
              <?php the_time('Y.m.d') ?><br>
              <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            </a>
          </li><br>
    
          <?php
            endwhile;
            echo '</ul>';
            my_paginate($my_query1);
            wp_reset_postdata();
          endif;
          ?>
        </div>
    
        <!-- EVENT -->
        <div class="panel" id="two-panel">
          <?php
          $my_query2 = new WP_Query(
            array(
              'post_type' => 'post',
              'paged' => $paged,
              'posts_per_page' => 3,
              'category_name' => 'event',
            )
          );
    
          if ($my_query2->have_posts()):
            echo '<ul>';
            while ($my_query2->have_posts()):
              $my_query2->the_post();
          ?>
          <li>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
              <?php the_title(); ?><br>
              <?php the_time('Y.m.d') ?><br>
              <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            </a>
          </li><br>
    
          <?php
            endwhile;
            echo '</ul>';
            my_paginate($my_query2);
            wp_reset_postdata();
          endif;
          ?>
        </div>
    
      </div>
    </div>

</div\>
</section\>
```

Functions.php

```
function my_paginate($query_name = '')
{
  $settings = array(
    'side_range' => 3,
    // 現在ページの左右の表示数.
    'txt_prev' => '<',
    // 一つ戻るテキスト.
    'txt_next' => '>',
    // 一つ進むテキスト.
    'txt_first' => '|<',
    // 最初へ移動テキスト.
    'txt_last' => '>|', // 最後へ移動テキスト.

  );

  if ('' !== $query_name) {
    $query = $query_name;
  } else {
    global $paged, $wp_query;
    $query = $wp_query;
  }
  $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
  $showitems = ($settings['side_range'] * 2) + 1;
  $pages = $query->max_num_pages;

  if (1 !== $pages) {
    echo "<div class=\"pagination\">\n";
    echo "  <ul class=\"pagination__list\">\n";
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $pages; $i++) {
      if (1 !== $pages && (!($i >= $paged + $settings['side_range'] + 1 || $i <= $paged - $settings['side_range'] - 1) || $pages <= $showitems)) {
        echo ($paged === $i) ? 
          '    <li class="pagination__item--current">' . esc_html($i) . "</li>\n" :
          '    <li class="pagination__item"><a href="' . esc_url(get_pagenum_link($i)) . '">' . esc_html($i) . "</a></li>\n";
      }
    }
    echo "  </ul>\n";
    echo '  <p class="pagination__pos">Page ' . esc_html($paged) . '/' . esc_html($pages) . "</p>\n";
    if ($paged > 2 && $paged > $settings['side_range'] + 1 && $showitems < $pages) {
      echo '  <a class="pagination__btn--first" href="' . esc_url(get_pagenum_link(1)) . '">' . esc_html($settings['txt_first']) . "</a>\n";
    }
    if ($paged > 1) {
      echo '  <a class="pagination__btn--prev" href="' . esc_url(get_pagenum_link($paged - 1)) . '">' . esc_html($settings['txt_prev']) . "</a>\n";
    }
    if ($paged < $pages) {
      echo '  <a class="pagination__btn--next" href="' . esc_url(get_pagenum_link($paged + 1)) . '">' . esc_html($settings['txt_next']) . "</a>\n";
    }
    if ($paged < $pages - 1 && $paged + $settings['side_range'] - 1 < $pages && $showitems < $pages) {
      echo '  <a class="pagination__btn--last" href="' . esc_url(get_pagenum_link($pages)) . '">' . esc_html($settings['txt_last']) . "</a>\n";
    }
    echo "</div>\n";
  }
}
```